# How to specify outbound IP for specific applications on multiple venets?

Tags: vps

I'm having problems with proxy/relay applications such as a BNC. I have a CentOS 5.6 VPS with 2 IP addresses which are virtual adapters (venet0:0 and venet0:1) under venet0.

In these applications I can choose which IP address to bind to (IP address of venet0:1) but when they create an outbound connection, it is done through venet0:0.

These are my current settings (found using webmin):

**Interfaces**

```
Name    Type        IP Address      Netmask         Status   
lo      Loopback    127.0.0.1       255.0.0.0       Up
        Loopback    ::1             128             Up
venet0  Unknown     127.0.0.1       255.255.255.255     Up
      venet0:0  Unknown (Virtual)   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx     255.255.255.255     Up
      venet0:1  Unknown (Virtual)   xxx.xxx.xxx.yyy     255.255.255.255     Up
```

**Route and Gateways**

```
Destination Gateway     Netmask     Interface   
169.254.0.0 None        255.255.0.0 venet0
Default Route   None                venet0
::1     ::      128     lo
```

Please can someone help me figure out how to configure the VPS?

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the default routes you do not want. The command **ip route list** should give you three entries. For example, on my Debian VPS, I get :

```
192.0.2.1 dev venet0  scope link 
default via 192.0.2.1 dev venet0  src 10.15.4.62 
default via 192.0.2.1 dev venet0  src 10.15.4.61
```

I want the VPS to use 10.15.4.61 for outgoing connections, not 10.15.4.62, so I type :

```
ip route del default via 192.0.2.1 dev venet0 src 10.15.4.62
```

Now I have a single default route, and my VPS will use the IP I want.